# Network stats for a program

Tags: linux, networking, command-line

On Windows this is quite easy using Process Hacker. Suppose I want to know how many megabytes my torrent client has recieved and sent on Linux. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `nethogs`, but it only accumulates statistics since you started it. So if you combine with `screen` or `tmux` you could leave it running between terminal sessions and occasionally check it.

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39941877/12771809) `nethogs` is used in trace mode, which you could output to a logfile and also keep running. Then you could just see the current statistic by looking at the last line in the log at any time.

There are other options (like Zabbix or Nagios), but these involve installing more complex "system management" solutions with daemons and/or database backends, with the advantage you can have web dashboards to check status.

HTH,

ppenguin